# Change Crop Ratio in Blogger Thumbnail Widget

Tags: javascript, widget, thumbnails, blogger

So, I have this Blogger widget and I want to change the crop of the automated thumbnails. In this setup, it automatically changes the size and crop variable in the below link from S400, s1600 etc. to "S72-c" (see example below). What I want it to do is, change the SXXX to any size I want and at the same time, keep the original crop, in other words, remove the "-c" from the resulting thumbnail. Thanks!

http://image.com/_XXXXXXX/**s400**/image.jpg

http://image.com/_XXXXXXX/**s72-c**/image.jpg

Here's the widget code:

```
    <style>img.recent_thumb {padding:1px;width:65px;height:65px; Border: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224);  float:left;margin:0 10px 5px 0;}.recent_posts_with_thumbs {float: right;width: 100%;min-height: 80px;margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;padding: 0;font-size:11px;}ul.recent_posts_with_thumbs li {padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:5px;min-height:75px;}.recent_posts_with_thumbs a {text-decoration:none;}.recent_posts_with_thumbs strong {font-size:10px;}</style> 

<script style='text/javascript'>function showrecentpostswiththumbs(json) {document.write('<ul class="recent_posts_with_thumbs">'); for (var i = 0; i < numposts; i++) {var entry = json.feed.entry[i];var posttitle = entry.title.$t;var posturl;if (i == json.feed.entry.length) break;for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length;k++){

if(entry.link[k].rel=='replies'&&entry.link[k].type=='text/html'){var commenttext=entry.link[k].title;var commenturl=entry.link[k].href;}
if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {posturl = entry.link[k].href;break;}}var thumburl;try {thumburl=entry.media$thumbnail.url;}catch (error)


{
s=entry.content.$t;a=s.indexOf("<img");b=s.indexOf("src=\"",a);c=s.indexOf("\"",b+5);d=s.substr(b+5,c-b-5);if((a!=-1)&&(b!=-1)&&(c!=-1)&&(d!="")){
thumburl=d;} else thumburl='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_u4gySN2ZgqE/SosvnavWq0I/AAAAAAAAArk/yL95WlyTqr0/s400/noimage.png';

}


var postdate = entry.published.$t;var cdyear = postdate.substring(0,4);var cdmonth = postdate.substring(5,7);var cdday = postdate.substring(8,10);var monthnames = new Array();monthnames[1] = "Jan";monthnames[2] = "Feb";monthnames[3] = "Mar";monthnames[4] = "Apr";monthnames[5] = "May";monthnames[6] = "Jun";monthnames[7] = "Jul";monthnames[8] = "Aug";monthnames[9] = "Sep";monthnames[10] = "Oct";monthnames[11] = "Nov";monthnames[12] = "Dec";document.write('<li class="clearfix">');


if(showpostthumbnails==true) 
document.write('<img class="recent_thumb" src="'+thumburl+'"/>');
document.write('<b><a href="'+posturl+'" target ="_top">'+posttitle+'</a></b><br>');

if ("content" in entry) {
  var postcontent = entry.content.$t;}
else
if ("summary" in entry) {
  var postcontent = entry.summary.$t;}
else var postcontent = "";
var re = /<\S[^>]*>/g; 
postcontent = postcontent.replace(re, "");


if (showpostsummary == true) {

  if (postcontent.length < numchars) {
      document.write('<i>');
     document.write(postcontent);
      document.write('</i>');}
  else {
      document.write('<i>');
     postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, numchars);
     var quoteEnd = postcontent.lastIndexOf(" ");
     postcontent = postcontent.substring(0,quoteEnd);
     document.write(postcontent + '...');
      document.write('</i>');}
}

var towrite='';var flag=0;
document.write('<br><strong>');

if(showpostdate==true) {towrite=towrite+monthnames[parseInt(cdmonth,10)]+'-'+cdday+' - '+cdyear;flag=1;}

if(showcommentnum==true) 
{
if (flag==1) {towrite=towrite+' | ';}
if(commenttext=='1 Comments') commenttext='1 Comment';
if(commenttext=='0 Comments') commenttext='No Comments';
commenttext = '<a href="'+commenturl+'" target ="_top">'+commenttext+'</a>';
towrite=towrite+commenttext;
flag=1;
;
}

if(displaymore==true) 
{
if (flag==1) towrite=towrite+' | ';
towrite=towrite+'<a href="'+posturl+'" class="url" target ="_top">More -></a>';
flag=1;
;
}




document.write(towrite);

document.write('</strong></li>');
if(displayseparator==true) 
if (i!=(numposts-1))
document.write('<hr size=0.5>');
}document.write('</ul>');



}
</script>
```